# how to format csv with some sub items

Tags: python, csv

I want to format this sequence with some sub items.

```
[{'name': 'foo', 'total_price' : 15, 'price': [4, 2, 4, 5]}, 
 {'name': 'bar', 'total_price' : 10, 'price': [5, 2, 3]}]
```

I want to format this in excel like this:

```
+------+-------------+
| Name | Total Price |
+------+-------------+
| foo  | 15          |
+------+-------------+
|      | 4           |
+------+-------------+
|      | 2           |
+------+-------------+
|      | 4           |
+------+-------------+
|      | 5           |
+------+-------------+
| bar  | 10          |
+------+-------------+
|      | 5           |
+------+-------------+
|      | 2           |
+------+-------------+
|      | 3           |
+------+-------------+
```

It's like showing what are the amounts that was added to come up a total price

Now what I have tried so far is only like this.

```
"Name","Total Price"
{% for item in items %} {{ item.name }},{{ item.total_price }} {% endfor %}

+------+-------------+
| Name | Total Price | 
+------+-------------+
| foo  | 15          |
+------+-------------+
| bar  | 10          |
+------+-------------+
```

in a nutshell, I want to format it like the one above. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write out the name and total price in a row, then add rows for the individual prices:

```
for item in items:
    csv_writer.writerow([item['name'], item['total_price']])
    csv_writer.writerows(['', p] for p in item['price'])
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> items = [{'name': 'foo', 'total_price' : 15, 'price': [4, 2, 4, 5]}, {'name': 'bar', 'total_price' : 10, 'price': [5, 2, 3]}]
>>> f = StringIO()
>>> csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
>>> for item in items:
...     csv_writer.writerow([item['name'], item['total_price']])
...     csv_writer.writerows(['', p] for p in item['price'])
... 
>>> print f.getvalue()
foo,15
,4
,2
,4
,5
bar,10
,5
,2
,3
```